# How to display 3 buttons in a grid layout with the same width while also leaving a specific amount of whitespace between buttons 2 and 3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

What is the best way to create this 4 x 3 layout?

- Each button has a common margin on all sides
- Each button must be the same width
- Each button must have a height equal to its width
- Whitespace should take up 1% of the entire screens width
- Each row in the layout should take up the entire screen width
- LAYOUT
- Button 1 Button 2 Whitespace Button 3
- Button 4 Button 5 Whitespace Button 6
- Button 7 Button 8 Whitespace Button 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a LinearLayout having *orientation:horizontal* for each row.

Inside every row/linearlayout provide three buttons having the android:layout_width="0dip" and android:layout_weight as follows:

- Button1 android:layout_weight="33"
- Button2 android:layout_weight="33"
- View android:layout_weight="1"
- Button3 android:layout_weight="33"

The sum goes to 100 and you'll get 1% of space between Button2 and 3 :)

Comment: Thanks Andrea!  I have a couple of new requirements and can't seem to get it to work using the linearlayout weighting approach.  Here's basically what my layout would need to look like: http://1drv.ms/1qaE7sE

Comment: Hello :) I'd mark this answer as correct and open a new question since this is a whole different problem ( easily solvable :) )

Comment: Done.  Thank you for the help.  I've posted a new question for the updated requirements here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691698/how-to-display-9-buttons-in-a-grid-layout-with-the-same-width-and-separated-into